# The closure of a null nowhere dense set is null?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

A set like the rationals has Lebesgue measure 0 and its closure are the real numbers which has positive Lebesgue measure. However Q is dense. If a set where to be nowhere dense and also null what would the measure of its closure be in R?

Comment: Anything whatever.

Comment: How can it be anything?

Comment: look up "fat cantor set". There is a nowhere-dense compact set $K$ with $0<m(K)<1$. Hence for any $r>0$ you can get $m(K)=r$...

Comment: I have seen it, however it has positive measure but it's not the closure of a set with null measure,

Comment: Really? How do you prove it's not the closure of a null set???

Comment: My reasoning is that a set such as Smith-Volterra-Cantor is closed therefore it's the closure of itself which is not null

Comment: Hint: In fact any closed subset of the line is the closure of a countable subset.

Comment: ??? $E=\overline E$ and $m(E)>0$, so what? The question is whether _there exists_ a null set $A$ with $E=\overline A$.

Comment: The "fat Cantor set" is the closure of the set of the endpoints of the intervals formed at each stage of its construction.

Answer (score 1):

A [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set), a small modification of the construction of the middle-third Cantor set in $[0,1]$ is nowhere dense and compact and can be given any measure $m>0$. A countable dense set $D$ of this fact Cantor set is then a nowhere dense null-set of measure $m$.

Nowhere dense and null-set are unrelated. (But in the reals a closed null set is nowhere dense).

Comment: *Nowhere dense and null-set are unrelated* --- There is one sometimes useful relation when closures are done first, namely a set whose closure is null is automatically nowhere dense.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro True, because non-empty open sets have measure $>0$. This is not the case in all spaces but an artefact of Euclidean spaces.